# how to parse simple xml

Tags: iphone, ipad

```
    <NewDataSet>
      <Table>
        <CaseId>743</CaseId>
        <PartyId>11100550</PartyId>
        <CartId>18</CartId>

      </Table>
      <Table>
        <CaseId>742</CaseId>
        <PartyId>11100549</PartyId>
        <CartId>1148</CartId>
        <BusinessID>19</BusinessID>

      </Table>
    </NewDataSet>


        NSData* data = [xmlResponseData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //   NSXMLParser *XMLparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    //    [XMLparser setDelegate:self];

        BOOL success;

        if (XMLparser) // addressParser is an NSXMLParser instance variable
            [XMLparser release];

        XMLparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
        [XMLparser setDelegate:self];
        [XMLparser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:YES];

        success = [XMLparser parse];   // return value not used
        // if not successful, delegate is informed of error 

       if(success)
            NSLog(@"Sucess Parsed");
        else
            NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

    //  NSLog(@"Parsed string : %@",valueForItem);

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
        attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"]) {
            caseID_List = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        }
        NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);

        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"CaseId"]) {

        }

    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

        if(!currentElementValue) 
            currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
        else
            [currentElementValue appendString:string];

        NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);


    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
      namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

      if([elementName isEqualToString:@"NewDataSet"]) 
return;
    }
```

I need only CaseId to store from the given xml.  Can any one advice me on this simple parsing!

For me its looping! and getting all details

Comment: why don't you use GDataXML parser.. its easy to use and parse any kind of xml..

Comment: can u tell me if u got the answer for your question as i am dealing with the same problem here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Below Code.Where Table is NSObject Class with the CaseId,PartyId,CartId as a properties in this class.If you have the xml url just called loadXMLByURL method with URl.After parsing you will get Each Object in TableArray which have the Table object with above properties.

```
NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSXMLParser     *parser;
Tweet           *currentTweet;
bool            isStatus;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _tweets         = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

    - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"Table"]) 
        {
            currentTable = [Table alloc];
                isStatus = YES;
        }
    }

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (isStatus) 
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"CaseId"]) 
        {
            currentTable.CaseId = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"PartyId"]) 
        {
            currentTable.PartyId = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"CartId"]) 
        {
            currentTable.CartId = currentNodeContent;
        }

    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"Table"]) 
    {
        [self.tableArray addObject:currentTable];
        currentTable = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: Hi Sandy I try use your code stuff and manipulated in to my xml parser its working !