# Problems with parsing an xml into objects in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML with some id and in each one of them there's a data, I am trying to parse all the XML so in the end I'll get an objects like this:

```
A1Object[a1,a1,a1,a1]
A2Object[a2,a2,a2,a2]
```

The problem is to parse first only A1,A2...

The xml:

```
<response>
    <tmm>
        <tm id="A1"><DocumentElement>
            <cell>
                <name>Tom</name>
                <lastName>LastNameTom</lastName>
            </cell>
            <cell>
                <name>Tom1</name>
                <lastName>LastNameTom1</lastName>
            </cell>
        </tm>
        <tm id="A2">
            <cell>
                <carType>5</carType>
                <catId>4545</carId>
            </cell>
            <cell>
                <carType>6</carType>
                <catId>565656</carId>
            </cell>
        </tm>
        <tm id="A3">...</tm>
    </tmm>
</response>
```

I have for each object (a1,a2...) his interfase with his fields

I am trying the next thing:

```
  if (xmlDocument != nil)
        {
            NSArray *nodes = [xmlDocument nodesForXPath:@"//cell" error: nil];
            if (nodes != nil)
            { 
                for (CXMLNode *node in nodes)
                {
                     A1 *a1Object = [[A1 alloc] init];

                    for (int i = 0; i < [node childCount]; i++)
                    {
                        CXMLNode *child = [node childAtIndex: i];
                        NSString *str = [child stringValue];
                        if ([[child name] isEqualToString: @"name"])
                        { 
                            a1Object.A1FacilityId = ([str length] > 0) ? str : nil;
                        }
                        if ([[child name] isEqualToString: @"lastName"])
                        { 
                            a1Object.A1FacilityStreetName = ([str length] > 0) ? str : nil;
                        }                      
                    }

                    [self.A1s addObject:a1Object];
                    [a1Object release];
                }            
            }
        }
```

How I can improve that so in the end I get it like:

```
A1Object[a1,a1,a1,a1]
A2Object[a2,a2,a2,a2
```

Comment: I have given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983514/how-to-parse-simple-xml/11984080#11984080) the answer for parsing a xml file .Please check and modify as per your xml feed
OR
Check this [tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/)

Comment: In did start element :  currentObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"]; and in didEndElement assign to the appropriate array based on the current object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TBXML to parse XML.

http://tbxml.co.uk/